# Detecting and applying specific font to capitalised letters css

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using an open source font for use in an internal project, and am having trouble applying the font based on case. There is a variation for every type of case (ie uppercase, lowercase, numbers, currency, math, punctuation), and while I can apply the font to a  block of text no problem, everytime I use an uppercase (or number/punctiation) that uppercase (or ...) character doesn't seem to get the font applied, and so looks strange.

How do you apply a font based on text case in css (or javascript)?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at the character set of the font you have downloaded and make sure it has all versions of the characters seems daft that they haven't included uppercase characters, especially if it is open source

Comment: they have seperated the case into different fonts (mad as that seems) for example in the pack I have contain the same font with .uppercase.regular / .lowercase.regular etc in them

Comment: why don't you wire them up as fallbacks then: `font-family: font, font-uppercase, font-maths, etc`  Not sure if this would work though as not sure if the font is found but nothing is rendered

Comment: thats not totally crazy... hang on will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The answer: As pete suggested wire them as a fallback such as : font-family: font, font-uppercase, font-maths, etc worked great!! 
Many thanks Pete